# jquery is not working in wordpress template

Tags: php, jquery

this is my test form,in this form i want to apply change function and keyup functions,but it doesnt work

```
<form>
<div id="main" class="group1">
     <div>
        <label>Choose group</label>
        <select name="group " id="sktest">
            <option value="group1">Group 1</option>
            <option value="group2">Group 2</option>
            <option value="group3">Group 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="group1_opts">
        <label>G1 option </label><input id="sk" type="text" name="opt1">
    </div>
    <div class="group1_opts group2_opts">
        <label>G1/G2 option</label><input id="sk" type="text" name="opt2">
    </div>
    <div class="group2_opts group3_opts">
        <label>G2/G3 option</label><input id="sk" type="text" name="opt3">
    </div>
    <div class="group3_opts">
        <label>G3 option</label><input id="sk"type="text" name="opt4">
    </div>
</div>
</form>

    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
<script
              src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("#sktest").change(function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
    $("#sk").keyup(function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

i am trying to alert messages but it doesent work .please help me/...

Comment: **`id` should be unique per page**

Comment: i did this  <script>
    $("#sktest").change(function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
    $("#sk").keyup(function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
</script> but its also doesent work

Answer (score 0):

First of all Id should be unique. So in case you needed to bind same function with multiple elements, use **class** then.

Second, put your js function inside $(document).ready

I checked when putting your function in $(document).ready() plus if you have mutliple ids it will fire only for the first element.

It has nothing to do with wordpress

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
alert('jQuery loaded');
$("#sktest").change(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
$("#sk").keyup(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Pankaj Waghmare user JQuery instead of $.
Example : JQuery(document).ready();.

Hope this helps u.